# Array Search with Array Column does not work in array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have an array created from a json_decode, which looks like below, creating an array of objects. I have 2 questions, one being the functionality not working as intended, and 2, a performance related question. This is what I have:

```
{
    "info": {
        "options": [{
                "optionID": 123
            },
            {
                "optionID": 456
            },
            {
                "optionID": 789
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the `json_decode` is done elsewhere and will break a lot of other code if changed, so that is not an option to pass `true` to the json_decode.

```
$data = file_get_contents('/datastore.json');
$options = json_decode($data);
var_dump($idpassed);
var_dump($options);
```

The above produces:

```
int(123)
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#551 (16) {
    ["optionID"]=> (int)123
  },
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)607 (16) {
    ["optionID"]=> (int)456
  },
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#663 (16) {
    ["optionID"]=> (int)789
  }
}
```

I am trying to find if the 'optionID' property exists, depending on a value set elsewhere. I am therefore doing this:

```
if (array_search($idpassed, array_column($options, 'optionID')) !== FALSE) {
   echo "the option exists!";
} else {
   echo "the option does not exist!";
}
```

**Question 1:**
If `$idpassed` is `456` or `789`, this always returns true, exactly as I expect. However, if I pass in `123`, it fails, presumably because the array of `options` index is `0` which is *falsey*. What other options have I got for `!== FALSE` for this method? Everything I have tried (e.g. === false, or === true, don't work, because of the `0` key returned.

As an alternate approach, I just did a simple foreach, which works as expected:

```
$exists = false;
foreach ($options as $option) {
   if ($option->optionID === $idpassed) {
       $exists = true;
       break;
   } 
}
print_r($exists)
```

This method returns true for `123`, `456` and `789` and false for anything I don't expect.
**Question 2:**
So which method is better for performance, and why? I believe the array_column method *should* be faster because it's a direct C implementation, but not 100% sure.

Many thanks!

Comment: maybe that `123` isn't what you think it is, given what your input above gives, the code block your already have works as expected. https://3v4l.org/a30mV

Comment: I did a var_dump of both `$idpassed` and `$option->optionID` and both are `integer 123`.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible with the info we have so far, https://3v4l.org/YUGOl shows that this works fine & as expected.

Comment: Ok, I think I may have found the problem. json_decode($options, true) - the true is not set, therefore I have an array of objects. So the question is, how to do this with an array of objects?

Answer (score -1):

The type is string, so use:
$idpassed = '123';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).